# check if package is uninstalled permanantly -linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

I am using Manjaro,  and my root partition is sort of full, so I want to uninstall some packages.

I have downloaded IntelliJ from the official website and now I want to uninstall it.

I have tried :

```
sudo pacman -Qs intellij
```

also

```
sudo pacman -Qs idea-UI
```

But I can't locate the package.

The `bin`, `plugin`, `license`, `lib` ... and all the packages are in `/home/charbel/idea-IU-213.6461.79/`

Comment: Is `/home` a separate partition from `/`? Please post the results of `df -h`; add to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that You did not install `intelij` with `pacman` package manager.
Therefore, you can run `rm -ir /home/charbel/idea-IU-213.6461.79/` or right-click the directory in the graphical environment to remove them.
Before you remove them, **you check not to contain IMPORTANT files**.

Comment: okay but the folder size of ```/home/charbel/idea-IU-213.6461.79/``` is only 4KiB so is it really the the whole app?

Comment: Sorry I never used IntelliJ IDEA. I found URL that gets [IntelliJ tarball](https://download-cdn.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2021.3.2.tar.gz). It is about 912MB. Question. Does there exist `bin`, `license` directories, and `build.txt` file in your `/home/charbel/idea-IU-213.6461.79/` directory?